# Modifying NavigationBar in code modifies multiple NavigationBars in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a storyboard with 3 different NavigationControllers:

[image]

In my root controller of the first NavigationController i'm adding a PageControl in code:

```
func addPageControlToNavigationBar() {

    let navBarsize = navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.size
    let origin = CGPointMake(navBarsize.width/2, navBarsize.height/2)

    navigationController?.delegate = self

    pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(navBarsize.width/2, navBarsize.height/2, 0, 0))
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 2
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, 20, 20))
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(pageControl)
}
```

When i'm performing a segue to the 2nd NavigationController the PageController is there aswell. I only wanted it to be present in the first ViewController.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewWillAppear` just add the page control,

```
self.addPageControlToNavigationBar()
```

In `viewWillDisappear` just remove the page control,

```
pageControl.removeFromSuperview()
```

so that it will not affect in any other view controllers